# Covert PHP Array with stdClass Obect into HTML list

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a PHP  multidemsional array that look like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 1 [name] => Lesotho [code] => LE ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 2 [name] => Malawi [code] => MW ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 3 [name] => Zimbabwe [code] => ZI ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 4 [name] => Uganda [code] => UG ) 
  [4] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 5 [name] => Eswatini [code] => SZ ) 
  [5] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 6 [name] => Mozambique [code] => MZ ) 
  [6] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 7 [name] => Haiti [code] => HT ) 
)
```

I'm trying to convert this in HTML
do i have to convert into an array using json_encode() or can I directly use a for loop?

```
<ul>
  <li>name</li>
  <ul>
    <li>id</li>
    <li>code</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which ways have you tried so far and failed with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to do it

```
 $keys = array_keys($countries);
 for($i = 0; $i < count($countries); $i++) {
     echo $keys[$i] . "{<br>";
     foreach($countries[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
         echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";
     }
     echo "}<br>";
 }
111
```